# Vue template inlining results in typescript errors not shown by Volar/vue-tsc

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, vue-component

I'm using Vue 3 + typescript + webpack with SFCs using . I noticed that although my application runs fine using the webpack dev server, when I run a production build I get a lot of mysterious errors in the JS compiled from my templates. Digging in, the errors seem to be situations like the following:

```
<parent v-if="blah != null">
  <child :something="blah.whatever" />
</parent>
```

Volar/vue-tsc reports this as fine, because it is totally fine and typesafe. However, vue template inlining then converts this into an optimized js form - only in a production build:

```
// pseudocode
blah != null ? createChunk(() => h('child', {something: blah.whatever})) : createComment()
```

Typescript then correctly reports an error - since we're reading blah.whatever in a callback, there's no guarantee that the check that blah != null still holds true anymore. Of course it will be true still, but Typescript has no way of knowing.

Similarly, a check like `blah != null && blah.whatever` gets converted to `_unref(blah) != null && _unref(blah).whatever`. Of course, Typescript has no way of knowing that the two function calls will return the same thing so it believes that the second condition is not typesafe.

This seems to be caused by something called template inlining within the `vue-loader`, which is enabled only for  components in a production build.

**Has anyone run into this and figured out a way to prevent these sorts of errors?**

Comment: erm, source maps?

Comment: where/how are you seeing typescript errors in compiled production code?  typescript doesn't run in the browser, javascript does, hence part of the build process is transpiling typescript code to javascript, including the stripping of all typings (they'd just be considered invalid javascript).  Can you include in your question the actual errors and stack traces that you're seeing?

Comment: if you're looking at typescript errors in your IDE while looking at production javascript code, just ignore them

Comment: These are build errors. Here's an example one:

  `ERROR in /Users/noa/Documents/code/hearth/packages/binaries/ui-v2/src/app/soot/components/Home.vue.ts
  80:37-39
  [tsl] ERROR in /Users/noa/Documents/code/hearth/packages/binaries/ui-v2/src/app/soot/components/Home.vue.ts(80,38)
        TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type '({ __typename?: "Connection" | undefined; id: string; displayName: string; }[] | undefined)[K]'.`

This is output for the command `webpack -c webpack.web.config.js --config-name production`.

Comment: The line number in the error is larger than the number of lines in the <script> tag in Home.vue - it comes from the code that the <template> compiles to